2003 Honda Shadow 1100 cutoff while idling
My 2003 Honda Shadow 1100 cc just cut off while idling now usually I would just jump start it with the jump box this time there's no power anywhere I checked my fuses they're good the battery power is good anybody know what's wrong

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does your Shadow have a kickstart? If so, have you tried it?

I had a very similar issue with my 1100 spirit, it turned out to be a loose battery connection.  It happened a while ago, seemed to be sporadic too, once the bike started it was fine but, I would have difficulty starting it as it would not crank.  It's really funny now, as I was actually trying to bump start ( like, push it and then pop the clutch to try and start ) over a loose connection XD
